# Render RDF and RDFS

Tags: xml, rdf, rdfs

I have a RDF file and its RDFS and I need to view the ontology schema graphically.
What I would like to see is a schema similar to the ER diagram.

Is there any graphical tool which shows the ontology structure in such a way?

Best regards

Answer (score 4):

There are many visualizers for RDFS and/or OWL schemas. Many of them are available as plugins for editors such as Protege, NeOn toolkit or TopBraid Composer.

As an standalone tool you could try turtled: https://github.com/mhausenblas/turtled

For a more customizable graph generation you could try AR2DTool (https://github.com/idafensp/ar2dtool) (this is a personal project in which I'm currently working and it's still on beta).

Comment: I would recommend using Protégé and then add the plugin you need. It is a great tool for such a purpose and it is also open source.

Comment: I tried both of the tools user2472347 suggested. turtled doesn't fit my needs because my RDF file is not in turtle syntax. Regarding AR2DTool, I didn't find any documentation about the settings file I have to pass by the command line to the jar. Do you have any clue about this?

@magnudae: I'll try Protege